# Написание кода PHP

Tags: php, циклы, дата

Я начинающий программист. Мне нужно написать небольшой код. Есть число 2833, нужно вывести день в формате 12.09.2018 с этим числом, затем следующий день 13.09.2018 с числом 2858. И каждый следующий день с числом больше предыдущего на 25. Код должен закончится на 10033.
Цикл я написал

```
<?php
for ($a = 2833; $a <=10033; $a=$a+25) {
    echo "Рейтинг : ". $a . "<br />";
 }
 ?>
```

Есть предположение, что дату нужно перевести в строку и создать цикл, который бы прибавлял 86400 и снова переводил в дату. Как толково можно это сделать? 
Все результаты вывести в столбик на странице

Comment: Делайте шаги: 1) Заводите с цикл с шагом 25 и до 10000. Проверяете что работает и выводит 2) создайте объект даты и плюсуйте по дню, проверяя что это работает 3) объединить шаги 2 и 3

Comment: И в чем, собственно, вопрос?

Comment: На 10000 закончить не получится. Невозможно получить 10000 прибавляя по 25 к 2708.

Comment: @Эникейщик ну надо сделать проверку >= 10000

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$A = [];
for ($a = strtotime('12 September 2018'); $a <= strtotime('27 June 2019'); $a += 86400) {
    $A[] = $a;
}

$B = []; 
for ($b = 2833; $b <= 10033; $b += 25) {
    $B[] = $b;
}

foreach ($A as $k => $v) {
    echo date('d.m.Y', $v) .' — '. (isset($B[$k]) ? $B[$k] : '-') . PHP_EOL; // .'<br />';
}
```

Comment: какой увлекательный способ форматирования кода. Вы это понимаете вообще?

Answer (score 0):

Для работы з датой есть замечательная функция `strtotime`, которая может работать с относительной датой через конструкции вида `+10 days`. Добавляем в цикл еще один счетчик по дням (увеличивать будем "вручную" в цикле). И споьзуем это второе счетчик для увеличения дней:

```
$startDate = strtotime("12.09.2018");
$days = 0;
for ($a = 2833; $a <= 10033; $a = $a + 25) {
    echo "Рейтинг : ". $a . " за дату " . date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+{$days} days", $startDate)) . "<br />";
    $days++;
}
```